# Linking IFTTT to my Facebook business page, rather than my personal page

Tags: facebook-pages, if-this-then-that

I want to get IFTTT to automatically put whatever I post on my Facebook **business** page into my Google+ Business page, Twitter, Panoramio, Flicker etc. However, when I try to link IFTTT to my Facebook account, it wants to link to my personal page. How do I tell it to link to my business page?

Answer (score 6):

There is a clear option for using your Facebook Page while creating a recipe. I am not sure if you tried that.

[image]

Comment: His question, and mine as well is about linking to a facebook BUSINESS page, which does not have its own login. Its under the umbrella of your homepage . The fb link on ifft is for your homepage.